# Can't access to parent div angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, input, components

I've got a parent component in which i have this layout:

```
<div #content>
   <chat-dialog></chat-dialog>
</div>
```

in this component (AppComponent) I defined the @Input of content

```
@Input()
content: ElementRef;
```

and then, in the child component I tried to access to the content in this way:

```
 content: any;
 constructor(@Inject(AppComponent) private parent: AppComponent) { 
    this.content = parent.content;
    console.log("content", this.content);
  }
```

But content is always undefined.

Comment: To be safe that `#content` is defined try to move logic from constructor to ngAfterViewInit (https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit)

Comment: In which way? Do you mean in the parent component?

Comment: Inside child component.

Comment: hmm, property doesn't exists

Comment: it's always undefined

Comment: Is the above template for the app component? In that case, @Input decorator doesn't makes an sense. Shouldn't it be ViewChild('content') content: ElementRef;

Comment: if possible, could you give some explanations of your objective/need to access parent. Depending your answer, it could be useful to consider other way to achieve same goal.